# Taylor approximation for function of a random variable

Tags: random-variable, moments, approximation, taylor-series, stochastic-approximation

There is a function $f$ whose domain is the space of CDFs on $\mathbb{R}_+$ and whose range is $[0,1]$, e.g. $f$ maps a CDF on to a real number. Further, $f$ is continuous, increasing with respect to first-order stochastic dominance, and has $I(\delta_d) = d$ for every $d \in \mathbb{R}_+$.

My question is, when doing a linear Taylor approximation of $f(X)$, where $X$ is a CDF, around a deterministic outcome $d$, under what circumstances is it permissible to write:

$f(X) \approx f(d) + f'(d) (E(X) - d)$?

(Here, abuse notation and let E(X) be the expectation for a random variable whose CDF is X).

The main concern I have is the $E(X)$ part as $f$ need not be linear in probabilities and could even be a composite function like $f = \left(E[X^{1/2}]  \right)^2$.

Comment: I don't think you should write it as $f(X)$ is it's actually a function of $E[X]$ or $E[X^{1/2}]$ instead of a function of $X$. Notation $f(X)$ suggests that the value depends on the random value taken by $X$, not on the constant expectation (which depends only on the distribution, not on the random variable itself).

Comment: Please explain what your notation "$\{1/2,a;1/2,b\}$" means and how it might be related to the rest of your question, which never references this again.  //  What is a "deterministic" outcome?  A number? // Concerning your question, have you noticed that the left hand side "$f(X)$" is a *random variable* while the right hand side is a *number?*

Comment: @Stef, the function f maps a random variable on to a real number, but that mapping need not just be E[X] or E[X^1/2], which are just examples. The properties of f are specified in the question: f is continuous, strictly increasing with respect to FOSD, and f(x) = x for any degenerate lottery x (e.g. a lottery which takes on value x with 100% probability).

Comment: @whuber, it means a with 50% probability and b with 50% probability. A deterministic outcome is an outcome that occurs with 100% probability. For your third question, f(X) is not a random variable, it is a mapping from a random variable to a real number.

Comment: In order for a random variable to have a Taylor series expansion I would think that it needs to be a smooth function of the outcome space, which would be an unusual assumption. Are you sure this is what you want?

Comment: @Galen, in this case it is the function f which I want to Taylor approximate, and f is real valued. It maps random variables on to [0,1]. f is, by assumption continuous. So it should have a Taylor expansion. I am just not sure how to write the Taylor expansion because f's input is a random variable.

Comment: Oh, okay thank you for clarifying. I would have to agree with previous comments that an expectation operator (conditional or not) is required.

Comment: I guess we could say E[f] - would that help? In this case E[f] = f since f is real-valued.

Comment: @Galen  do you think this would be the answer? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_expansions_for_the_moments_of_functions_of_random_variables

Comment: You wrote above "the function $f$ maps a random variable on to a real number, but that mapping need not just be $E[X]$..." , but none of the examples you provide, either in that comment or in the question itself, map a random variable onto anything; $E[X]$ is a constant.  Are you sure you are mapping the random variable itself and not just constructing a function of the *expectation* of that random variable?

Comment: Yes, for example the second example =([^(1/2)])^2 is not a function of E[X] since E[X^(1/2)] is not the same as E[X]^(1/2).

Comment: It's still not a function of a random variable, though, since $E(X^{1/2})$ is a constant, not an r.v.  Consider my previous comment to end with "... constructing a function of the *expectation* of a function of that random variable" instead :)

Comment: @jbowman, that's fair enough. f is taking a random variable and mapping it to a real number. That's correct. But, the mapping can be anything that depends on the distribution.

Comment: Can you write the actual function you want to use?  That would clarify things since, so far, your statements, such as "f is taking a random variable and mapping it to a real number," conflict with your examples, confusing (some of) the readership.

Comment: I actually want to prove a theorem for any function that has these properties :)

Comment: A scalar is not itself a function, but constant functions are functions. Any cartesian product which is left total and right unique is a function.

Comment: @Galen But here it's a function of the probability distribution, not a function of the random variable.

Comment: @Stef Thank you for correcting me. I had not read carefully enough.

Comment: Since, after some edits, $f$ now appears to be a *functional* on a set of CDFs, could you explain what you mean by a "Taylor approximation" to it?

Comment: @whuber, sure, f goes from the set of CDFs to the real line. So a taylor approximation of f around the CDF of, say X with 100% probability.

Comment: In the context of your question (as it stands), that makes no sense.  You would have to conceive of the set of CDFs as being some kind of metric space and expand the CDF as powers of differences between CDFs in that space (perhaps like a [Frechet derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative))--but that's nothing like what your notation suggests.  I wonder whether you are trying to ask about something you have encountered but don't follow the notation it uses?  It would help us to have some context.

Comment: Maybe $X$ is a random variable with value in $\mathbb R ^+$, and $f:\mathbb R^+ \to [0, 1]$, and $d \in \mathbb R^+$, and you're trying to estimate $E[f(X)]$ using the Taylor expansion for $f$ at $d$?